# How to create a string variable with Quotation marks in it's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following text:

```
"{
  "iv": "QaVlP3rzrSNw3oRLqmXv7Q",
  "v": 1,
  "iter": 1000,
  "ks": 128,
  "ts": 64,
  "mode": "ccm",
  "adata": "",
  "cipher": "aes",
  "salt": "ffGgwesLMEg",
  "ct": "5QjHDbwuLIgYZFWvgIH4J5WZI514zJR0ucsmQ0jljYaOgCKNOWlnrpO0ipEVjQiA7hHfk7T7nXcjN2Yo10U+dGY5DMS+OfvZiGo6/kbBkgpFWEz28uwUl1zIRJ6NBfxULbMjyoUwPuxV05r87U5+H+WEuEiKCP7HWgQH0d68a8AEsvoVah1pDUWlYXom8+TqvTHwmm5Dyyv84h3JN8KHSEnum8ORXDGGNthif3LzirAULRzH0PlsJYrgtj+yOoIWuS0wAKPgwxRkAVchjRoFqEgwfYp+wawLC6oWwj8Mq1ERVyk"
}"
```

---

If I use a text file in same directory with this value, using jQuery:

```js
var text = jQuery.get('http://localhost/text.txt');
//This convert text to an Object...
```

and

```js
JSON.stringify(text)
// returns "{"readyState":1}"
```

So, is there any method to save this text in a variable?

Comment: If you want it in a variable as a string, just do `var foo = JSON.stringify(text);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [callback](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-url-data-success-dataType) to handle the response and set response type as `json`.

```
jQuery.get('http://localhost/text.txt', function(res){
   console.log(res);
}, 'json');
```

---

Or use [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method instead.

```
jQuery.getJSON('http://localhost/text.txt', function(res){
   console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json_variable = JSON.parse(jQuery.get('http://localhost/text.txt'));
```